PostgreSQL. Getting data from another table
I'm trying to get data from "users" table into 'user_id' and 'profile_fullname' rows from "profiles" table.
For example if a row has an id of 1 in the "users" table, then the 'user_id' should also be 1.
Same with the 'profile_fullname'.
Here's the code:
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_fullname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user_email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    user_password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE profiles (
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
    profile_fullname VARCHAR(60),
    profile_headline TEXT,
    profile_professional_headline TEXT,
    profile_website_link VARCHAR(200),
    profile_twitter_link VARCHAR(200),
    profile_facebook_link VARCHAR(200),
    profile_linkedin_link VARCHAR(200),
    profile_youtube_link VARCHAR(200),
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

I've tried researching the problem, but still seems to be unclear for me how to do it.
So how can i solve it?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. I.e. show us some sample table data and also the expected result (all as properly formatted text - not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

I assume your profiles table is empty and you are wanting to populate it with rows from the users table:
INSERT INTO profiles 
    SELECT id as user_id , user_fullname  as profile_fullname
    FROM users 

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-insert-values-into-a-table-from-a-select-query-in-postgresql

 select u.id,prof.profile_fullname
 from users as u
 join profiles as prof on u.id=prof.user_id
 where u.id=1 

you need this one?

I'm sorry for the confusion. I need the id from "users" and user_id from "profiles" to have the same values. Same with user_fullname from "users" and profile_fullname from "profiles", need them to have the same values. Hope that the request is understandable
